# Conducting plastic for capacitive touchscreens

Tags: touchscreen, capacitive

As I am disabled I have to use a headstick (see picture below) to do stuff on the computer. I also have a phone with a resistive touchscreen, which works well with my headstick.

[image: headstick]

But here is the problem: I cannot operate any devices with capacitive touchscreens, since the tip of the headstick is made of plastic. I heard, though, of conducting polymers, and wondered if my problem could be solved using those. So basically I thought of just making a new tip of such a conductive plastic.

What do you think about this approach? How expensive are these materials? What can yu say about their electrical properties vs. human skin? Would this be a good idea?

Would something different work? Like putting a little coil inside the tip of the headstick?

Comment: You've come to the right place to ask about the design of capacitive touchscreens and how to design a stylus for these screens, but (1) this is not a forum, and (2) this is not a place to ask about where to buy consumer electronics (like a [capacitive stylus](http://www.amazon.com/s?field-keywords=capacitive%20stylus) <- *Link to Amazon where you can buy the thing you need already built :)*).  I'll leave the technical question here, though, as the principles behind these styluses (styli?) are interesting.

Comment: FYI, you may find that a stylus is not enough - you may have to put a conductive plate as a sort of ground plane behind the phone - often times they will not register finger touches reliably if they are on a non-conductive surface but work fine when over a conductive one or held in a hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a quick experiment, a rolled up piece of metalized anti-static bag *sometimes* can work as a capacitive-screen stylus.

Comment: Yes, indeed. It did respond, but not very reliably though. Dont know if its because I didnt have good contact with the bag (wrapped it around the stick) or something else

Answer (score 1):

Instructables has a guide to [making your own "iPhone gloves"](http://www.instructables.com/id/Making-A-Glove-Work-With-A-Touch-Screen/). Here, they use some conductive thread between finger and outer surface. I assume you could do the same between your head and the end of the stick.

Answer (score 1):

The tip is presumably made of plastic to prevent damage to the touched surface.

Butyl rubbers are available which are loaded with carbon-black to make them conductive. A tip of such rubber with a conductive path may work.

You can mix carbon-black into various adhesives to make them conductive. This may includes silicone rubbers and epoxy resins. Conductive silicone rubber is liable to be non damaging.

Comment: Simply conductive is not enough, as lightly touching a capacitive phone screen with a blunt metal object will demonstrate.

Comment: @Chris Actually, a capacitive touchscreen reacts to metal. You can type with a spoon.

Comment: @Evgeni B.  Yours might react to metal objects, mine does not.  So it's not a reliable solution.

Comment: @Chris What kind of phone do you have? I tried a Samsung Galaxy S and a Sony Experia Arc and both responded well to touches with metal

Answer (score 1):

Capacitive touch screen systems react to a local change of capacitance on the touch panel. Human finger as well as conductive material like a coin are working because electronic charges attracted by them. Putting a conductive surface on top of an insulator (the touch screen cover is like an insulator) is making a capacitor, right?

What is important is not only the conductive property of the touching material, but also **the size of contact area**. The larger the better!

Remind this formula [image]