# Capacitive Touch Screen Stylus circuit type of thing

Tags: capacitance, touchscreen, capacitive

I am trying to figure out how to make a circuit that works much like a stylus for capacitive touch screens such as on an iPhone.

Given it's going to be a simple experiment, I was thinking of using an Arduino as the controller.

I have watched several videos and articles regarding "Aurdino Triggering Touch Screen", but none of them work reliably.

A stylus on the other hand can trigger the screen reliably and from a distance.

**EDIT:** A Samsung stylus triggers a on-screen pointer from at least 2 cm distance, while the tip of the stylus is a button notifying the phone to do some action, such as painting.

So what I need for my final project is to put electronics inside of a small plastic box (1.5cm^3) and the cube need to be able to trigger a spot beneath itself on the screen at regular intervals.

Is this possible?

**EDIT:**

To clarify this is exactly what I am looking for:

Circuitry that is placed in a 1.5 cubic centimeter box that triggers a 5 millimeter diameter circle on the screen under the box causing a virtual finger-press.

Distance between screen and actual circuitry is aprox 1mm.

Comment: [Some info...](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/23036/how-can-a-capacitive-touch-screen-be-triggered-without-human-contact?rq=1)

Comment: The question linked by @JRE is much more clearly formulated. Yours is rather unclear, I must say. For example: *"A stylus can trigger the screen from a distance."* What distance? From what I know, the stylus must *touch* the screen to trigger it. *"my final project is to put electronics inside of a small plastic box"* Shoudn't you design the electronics first? *"I was thinking of using an Arduino as the controller"* Do you plan to fit the arduino in 1.5cm3? ...

Comment: @dim:  The question is no marvel of clarity, but I read it as Vaid wanting to trigger a touch screen using an Arduino output.

Comment: @dim I added some additional info about what a Samsung stylus can achieve.
Yes, I should design the electronics first, which is why I'm coming here for help first before I shrink everything down to a smaller circuit.
No, the Arduino is for the prototyping phase, later I'll use a smaller mcu, or no mcu at all if possible.

Comment: @JRE yes, that's basically what I want to do.

Comment: @vaid:  The could you please make the question clearer?  State explicitly what you want to do, and why.

Comment: @JRE yes sir. I added clarification at the bottom. Let me know if it is OK.